# Controller binding weirdness

Tags: ember.js

If I have the following controller:

```
myApp.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  type: 'objectController',
  name: 'my name',
  controller: {name: "my controller name"},
});
```

you'd expect that {{name}} would yield "my name" and it does.

However {{controller.name}} also yields "my name".

Is there a way to have a property called "controller" (it could be, say, a financial controller), and access through handlebars bindings?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. Calling `{{controller}}` seems to be referencing the actual controller, not the controller property on your controller.

Comment: hmm, that's a bummer! this means my app can't use anything called "controller"

Answer (score 1):

controller in the context you mention, refers to indexController. so if you want to access the controller property of indexController, you can do this:

```
{{controller.controller.name}}
```

however, I'd advice against the variable name "controller." Ember has several reserved keywords and controller is one of them. Weird things might occur when using reserved keywords, so I'd just stay away from them.

Comment: agreed. you'll almost certainly cause yourself big problems down the line if you use `controller` as a variable